# CakePHP 3.x Starting Auth component from other controller than AppController gives false result

Tags: mysql, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I am making a login for a part of a website.
Therefore I don't want to start the Auth in the AppController but in the actual Controller I need it in.

In PremiumController:

[...]

```
use Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent;
```

[...]

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'Basic' => ['userModel' => 'Clients'],
        'Form' => ['userModel' => 'Clients'],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Premium',
            'action' => 'login',
            'plugin' => false
        ],
        'authError' => 'Unauthorized Access',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'naam',
                    'password' => 'pass'
                ],
                'userModel'=>'Clients', //Other table than Users
                'passwordHasher' => [
                    'className' => 'Premium', //use MD5
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Premium',
            'action' => 'dashboard'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Search',
            'action' => 'index'
        ]
    ]);


}
```

[...]
 and lower the login part

```
public function login()
{

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

I don't get any result from this. The $user remains 'false'

How can I make this work and is there a way to proper debug the Auth component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller listens to the login-page and his exact request names.

The content of my login.ctp was this

```
    <?= $this->Form->input('username', ['type' => 'text', 'id' => 'username', 'label' => __('Login / E-mail'), 'placeholder' => __('Login / E-mail')]) ?>

    <?= $this->Form->input('password', ['type' => 'password', 'id' => 'password', 'label' => __('Wachtwoord'), 'placeholder' => __('Wachtwoord')]) ?>
```

I had to change it into

```
    <?= $this->Form->input('naam', ['type' => 'text', 'id' => 'username', 'label' => __('Login / E-mail'), 'placeholder' => __('Login / E-mail')]) ?>

    <?= $this->Form->input('pass', ['type' => 'password', 'id' => 'password', 'label' => __('Wachtwoord'), 'placeholder' => __('Wachtwoord')]) ?>
```

To parse the post-data request to the right fields.
My misunderstandig was that the Controller handeled this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign key in the session so that Auth will check for the existence of the key in the session.

Change your code like this,

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'Basic' => ['userModel' => 'Clients'],
    'Form' => ['userModel' => 'Clients'],
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'Premium',
        'action' => 'login',
        'plugin' => false
    ],
    'authError' => 'Unauthorized Access',
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'naam',
                'password' => 'pass'
            ],
            'userModel'=>'Clients', //Other table than Users
            'passwordHasher' => [
                'className' => 'Premium', //use MD5
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'loginRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'Premium',
        'action' => 'dashboard'
    ],
    'logoutRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'Search',
        'action' => 'index'
    ]
]);
$this->Auth->__set('sessionKey', 'Auth.client');
```

Comment: I guess in this case I should use $this->Auth->__set('sessionKey', 'Auth.Clients');
But no, this is not working. I don't get any error or warning that gives me a glimpse of what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This shows up when I searched for [cakephp 3 "sessionkey"](https://www.google.com/search?q=cakephp+3+%22sessionkey%22), so this goes for anyone needing to set a custom `sessionKey` in a CakePHP 3 application. In your `src/Application.php`:

```
$service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session', [
    'sessionKey' => 'MyAuthKey',
]);
```